Different proof techniques of the Atiyah-Singer index theorem
I am aware of the usual K-theoretical (cobordism, operator algebras) and heat kernel proofs of the index theorem, as answered in other questions in this site, e.g. here.
However, I recently read this paper, where in page 5, section 7), a stochastic proof is mentioned, without reference, apparently attributed to "Bismuth-Azenkott". I never heard of this approach and also wasn't able to find any reference or a way to contact the author. I also would like more details than those mentioned in that sketch.
So the question is: does anybody know about an stochastic approach to the proof of the index theorem? Are there other "not-so-mainstream" approaches? Such proofs ought to be more or less general in its context of applicability, I am just interested in learning about new perspectives.
Edit: the comments elucidated that Bismut and Azencott where the authors meant, which lead me to these notes explaining the probabilistic approach and some other viewpoints. I will read that, but am still open to other directions.

I think the paper mentioned there is The Atiyah-Singer theorems: a probabilistic approach I & II  J. Funct. Anal. 1984 by Bismut, but I don’t know any details.

@coLaideronnette I was guessing it had to be Bismut :) thanks! I will check that and add it as a full answer with details in case it is what I am looking for

Azenkott -> Azencott

If you want something in lecture notes/book form, the book Stochastic Analysis on Manifolds by Elton Hsu contains a full exposition of the stochastic approach to the Atiyah-Singer index theorem, along with the required background from differential geometry and stochastic analysis.
